# "glCreateProgram and glGetError return 0"

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I try to build simple commandline application benchmarking OpenGL on arm64-v8a phone. glCreateProgram returns 0 and glGetError as well which seems incorrect because some error had to occur if glCreateProgram doesn't return positive integer (at least according to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCreateProgram.xhtml).

Maybe my initlialization is incorrect?

```
bool init() {
    EGLDisplay display(eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY));
    bool is_initialized;
    if (!eglInitialize(display, nullptr, nullptr)) {
        return false;
    }
    check_err();
    static const EGLint attributes[] = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3, EGL_NONE};
    EGLContext context(eglCreateContext(display, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attributes));
    if (auto error = glGetError()) {
        std::cout << error << endl;
        return false;
    }
    //   eglBindApi();
    return true;
}

int main() {
    if (!init()) {
        cout << "init error" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    program = glCreateProgram();
    cout << program << " " << glGetError() << endl;

}
```

Comment: I think it can be 0 in case of no context or invalid context. Could it be you are missing some call on the context to make it valid?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `glGetError()` to test the error state of your EGL functions. You want to use `eglGetError()` instead; `glGetError()` only handles error states for the GL functions.

Comment: after replacing with eglGetError I get 12288 which is egl success code. So it looks as if egl run correctly

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call [`eglMakeCurrent`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglMakeCurrent.xhtml). This function is very important to tell OpenGL that when you call a `gl***` function, which *context* and which *surfaces* are affected by that function.

In order to call `eglMakeCurrent`, you have to [create a surface](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateWindowSurface.xhtml) first, which you forgot also.

I suggest you start with a sample code (like Hello Triangle/Cube) and modify the code to suite your need.